# How can use Appengine Blobstore with SpringBoot & Thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-app-engine, thymeleaf, blobstore

I try to use Appengine Blobstore in my App to send large file , so in my controller I do this to send blobstoreService in my page html with thymeleaf

```
private BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
        model.addAttribute("blobstoreService", blobstoreService);
```

this is the action in my form to send the request ;

```
 th:action="${blobstoreService.createUploadUrl(/upload)}"
```

and this my controller to handle the call

```
@PostMapping("/upload")
        public ResponseEntity<String> uploadVideo(HttpServletRequest req,  HttpServletResponse res){
  Map<String, List<BlobKey>> blobs = blobstoreService.getUploads(req);
        List<BlobKey> blobKeys = blobs.get("videoFile");
        if (blobKeys == null || blobKeys.isEmpty()) {
             res.sendRedirect("/");
          } else {
                BlobKey blobKey = new BlobKey(blobKeys.get(0).getKeyString());
                blobstoreService.serve(blobKey, res);
            }
}
```

I get this error

```
    ERROR 9044 --- [qtp204715855-22] o.s.b.w.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter  : Forwarding to error page from request [/_ah/upload/aglub19hcHBfaWRyIgsSFV9fQmxvYlVwbG9hZFNlc3Npb25fXxiAgICAgIDACQw] due to exception [null]

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.UploadBlobServlet.handleUpload(UploadBlobServlet.java:432) ~[appengine-api-stubs.jar:na]
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.UploadBlobServlet.access$000(UploadBlobServlet.java:70) ~[appengine-api-stubs.jar:na]
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.UploadBlobServlet$1.run(UploadBlobServlet.java:116) ~[na:na]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.UploadBlobServlet.doPost(UploadBlobServlet.java:113) ~[appengine-api-stubs.jar:na]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707) ~[servlet-api-3.1.jar:3.1.0]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) ~[servlet-api-3.1.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder$NotAsync.service(ServletHolder.java:1452) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:791) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$ChainEnd.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626) ~[na:na]
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:134) ~[na:na]
```

Any idea for this ! thank you in advance

Comment: can you share the code for `blobstoreService.createUploadUrl`?

Comment: @RafaelLemos , after adding some code I get a nother error , I added it to in error part  I get an NPE when I try to call `/upload` , the code of `blobstoreService.createUploadUrl` it's from api google

Comment: I believe the only thing that could be causing a NPE is this variable being null: `blobKeys.get(0).getKeyString()`